# How to switch android-ndk example to use gcc instead of clang?

Tags: gcc, gradle, android-ndk, clang

How to switch this example here to use gcc?:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/other-builds/ndkbuild/hello-libs

Is there a way to set this over the gradle files?

Comment: `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9` in Application.mk. Note that GCC is no longer supported as part of the NDK (hence why you're stuck with GCC 4.9), and will be removed altogether in some future NDK release.

Comment: @Michael gcc produces more optimized binaries than clang in android NDK

Comment: @noone GCC 4.9 produces better code than Clang 6.0? If that's the case in general you may want to file some bugs on the LLVM team. But regardless of that, GCC is still going to be removed from the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest ndk(18), gcc is no longer supported and you are forced to use clang.
I faced some problems switching to clang and I am considering switching to cmake as it is recommended.

About the argument that gcc is better

> gcc produces more optimized binaries than clang in android NDK

while there is some truth to this, there seems to be a lot of discussion on this topic that it is because of the gcc implicitly using -Bisymbolic which is bad. You can find in depth conversation on ndk github repo here

https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/495

Its quite long, but very insightful.